# "static interface method invocations are not supported in -source 7" despite using 1.8

Tags: vert.x, vert.x-webclient

This is the complete error message:

"*static interface method invocations are not supported in -source 7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface method invocations)*"

Here is the class:

```
public class UserVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Router router=Router.router(vertx);//IDE shows error message here
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }
}
```

Here are the project properties:
[image]

These are my dependencies:

```
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
```

And:

```
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
```

**Edit**:

I changed javaee-web-api version to 8 in pom.xml (It was 7), built with dependencies, and still getting the same error.

**Edit2**:

I changed vertx-web version to 4.0.0 in pom.xml, built with dependencies, and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I should choose source 8 in maven-compiler-plugin, this totally solved the problem:

```
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
```